# How to disable CloudWatch metrics for KPL/KCL with Spring Cloud Stream

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-kpl

I am using the Spring Cloud Stream Binder for Kinesis with KPL/KCL enabled. We would like to disable Cloudwatch metrics without having to manage the configuration of KPL and KCL ourselves (completely overriding the beans). We would like to use the same bean definition for the `KinesisProducerConfiguration` and each of the `KinesisClientLibConfiguration` besides the `KinesisProducerConfiguration.setMetricsLevel()` and `KinesisClientLibConfiguration.withMetricsLevel(...)` properties.

For reference, here is where the AWS beans are defined in the Spring Cloud Stream Kinesis Binder: [KinesisBinderConfiguration.java](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-aws-kinesis/blob/main/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/binder/kinesis/config/KinesisBinderConfiguration.java)

What would be the most effective way to do this?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The framework does not provide any of the `KinesisClientLibConfiguration`. It is your project responsibility to expose such a bean and with whatever options you need: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-aws-kinesis/blob/main/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis-docs/src/main/asciidoc/overview.adoc#kinesis-consumer-properties

> Starting with version 2.0.1, beans of `KinesisClientLibConfiguration` type can be provided in the application context to have a full control over Kinesis Client Library configuration options.

The producer side indeed is covered by the `KinesisProducerConfiguration` bean in the `KinesisBinderConfiguration`:

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "spring.cloud.stream.kinesis.binder.kpl-kcl-enabled")
public KinesisProducerConfiguration kinesisProducerConfiguration() {
    KinesisProducerConfiguration kinesisProducerConfiguration = new KinesisProducerConfiguration();
    kinesisProducerConfiguration.setCredentialsProvider(this.awsCredentialsProvider);
    kinesisProducerConfiguration.setRegion(this.region);
    return kinesisProducerConfiguration;
}
```

I don't see a big problem from here to declare such a bean in your own configuration with any additional properties you'd like to have, including the mentioned metrics.

If this still is not OK for you, you can do something like this bean injection into your own bean and mutate it whatever way you want:

```
@Bean
String configurerBean(KinesisProducerConfiguration kinesisProducerConfiguration)  {
   kinesisProducerConfiguration.setMetricsLevel();
   return null;
}
```

**UPDATE**

The consumer part:

This is a bean based on default config instance for KCL we create internally:

```
@Bean
KinesisClientLibConfiguration kinesisClientLibConfiguration() {
    return new KinesisClientLibConfiguration(this.consumerGroup,
                            this.stream,
                            null,
                            null,
                            this.streamInitialSequence,
                            this.kinesisProxyCredentialsProvider,
                            null,
                            null,
                            KinesisClientLibConfiguration.DEFAULT_FAILOVER_TIME_MILLIS,
                            this.workerId,
                            KinesisClientLibConfiguration.DEFAULT_MAX_RECORDS,
                            this.idleBetweenPolls,
                            false,
                            KinesisClientLibConfiguration.DEFAULT_PARENT_SHARD_POLL_INTERVAL_MILLIS,
                            KinesisClientLibConfiguration.DEFAULT_SHARD_SYNC_INTERVAL_MILLIS,
                            KinesisClientLibConfiguration.DEFAULT_CLEANUP_LEASES_UPON_SHARDS_COMPLETION,
                            new ClientConfiguration(),
                            new ClientConfiguration(),
                            new ClientConfiguration(),
                            this.consumerBackoff,
                            KinesisClientLibConfiguration.DEFAULT_METRICS_BUFFER_TIME_MILLIS,
                            KinesisClientLibConfiguration.DEFAULT_METRICS_MAX_QUEUE_SIZE,
                            KinesisClientLibConfiguration.DEFAULT_VALIDATE_SEQUENCE_NUMBER_BEFORE_CHECKPOINTING,
                            null,
                            KinesisClientLibConfiguration.DEFAULT_SHUTDOWN_GRACE_MILLIS,
                            KinesisClientLibConfiguration.DEFAULT_DDB_BILLING_MODE,
                            new SimpleRecordsFetcherFactory(),
                            DEFAULT_LEASE_CLEANUP_INTERVAL_MILLIS,
                            DEFAULT_COMPLETED_LEASE_CLEANUP_THRESHOLD_MILLIS,
                            DEFAULT_GARBAGE_LEASE_CLEANUP_THRESHOLD_MILLIS);
}
```

Whatever you see with `this.` has to be replaced with respective value from your env. Probably that `KinesisClientLibConfiguration.DEFAULT_METRICS_MAX_QUEUE_SIZE` is what you are looking for in this case.

The `this.consumerGroup` and `this.stream` must be same as in binding you want to configure consumer for.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply. Would you mind providing an example for the KCL consumer as well? I am struggling to figure out the best way to do this given that the many of the overloaded constructors have been deprecated

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer.